# regular expression for series of text

Tags: javascript, regex

I have Googled for RegExp of organization name, but I have not found any results.

The following are the conditions:

1. It should not accept only special or only numeric characters.
2. It should be like this: letters + special characters if any (optional) + numeric (optional).

I have written the following regular expression:

```
if (!/^(([a-zA-Z]+)+([!@_-]*)+([\s]?)+([a-zA-Z]*))$/.test(document.signup_form.field_67.value.trim())) {
    alert("Organization name should have only Alphanumeric & Special characters");
    document.signup_form.field_67.focus();
    return false;
}
```

The above is not working with the organization name "**I-Tech software pvt ltd**". Please suggest a better regular expression.

Comment: It seems like you use the `+` as a concatenation operator. It makes no sense to repeat a `+` after you already have applied a `+`, `*` of `?`.

Comment: So if I understand correctly your only requirement is that the first character is a letter? What else could follow that makes it an invalid organisation name?

Comment: Just use `/^[a-zA-Z][-\w!@\s]*$/`

Comment: So your only requirement is that it contains letters?

Answer (score 0):

That's because `I-Tech software pvt ltd` does not match your regex. There are symbols in between spaces in `I-Tech software pvt ltd`, but the regex doesn't allow that.

Solution that I think you are looking for might be something like this:

`/^([a-zA-Z][-\w!@\s]*)$/`

I haven't tested this, but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score -1):

You can use lookahead assertions to act as conditions in the string you're trying to match:

```
/^(?=(?:\w*)[A-Za-z]+)(?=(?:\w*)[!@_-]+)(?=(?:\w*)\d*).+$/
```

`(?=(?:\w*)[A-Za-z]+)` is the first lookahead, requiring that the match should contain at least one letter, in other words, like you state "to not accept only special or only numeric characters."

`(?=(?:\w*)[!@_-]+)` is the second lookahead, stating that there should be 0 or more special characters.  I don't think this is necessary to match, because in the previous lookahead, it requires at least one letter.

`(?=(?:\w*)\d*)` is the third lookahead, stating that there should be zero or more digits. Again, probably not necessary, but to illustrate your requirement in your question.

Finally, the string to actually match is `.+`, meaning there must be at least one character present in the field you're testing.  The `^` and `$` characters denote to check the whole string.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I'd like to learn why this was voted down.  If someone can provide insight to any errors in my answer, I'd appreciate it.  If I have an error, I'll be happy to edit my answer, or delete it.  Thanks!